# What is the difference between `marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal` and `marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR`?

Tags: .net

`marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)` is not documented anywhere and it's hard to interpret the stack trace without knowing what methods do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a little internal helper method that's called by the two public Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR() method overloads.  Don't shoot the messenger, it merely converts a COM error code (HR = HResult) to a managed exception and throws that exception.  The exception you get is *hopefully* an indication what went wrong.  Which is not usually that clear, COM error codes tend to be undescriptive, especially when no IErrorInfo is available.

Comment: Thank you- I've been looking all over the web with nothing on this particular method.